# how to use bind in sparql

Tags: android, sparql

i am working on ontology project in that i write a sparql query that sparql query work fine in protege 4.3 but when i use that sparql query in android i am getting exception please suggest any solution how can i use bind in android

my sparql query is

```
select ?_Email ?_ind ?_ind1 where {

   ?_ind rdf:type my:Accomodation .
  ?_ind my:hasStarRating ?_Email.
  ?_ind my:hasType ?_ind1.

   bind( str(?_Email) as ?_Email )
   bind( strafter(str(?_ind),str(my:)) as ?_ind  )
   bind( str(?_ind1) as ?_ind1 )
}
```

that shows the exception

```
Caused by: com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Lexical error at line 1, column 590.  Encountered: " " (32), after : "bind"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be use the androjena.  That uses an old version of Jena which does not have BIND.

And for BIND, it must be a fresh variable.

```
bind( str(?_Email) as ?_Email2 )
```

You may have more success with LET if you use ARQ's extended syntax (this has been around longer; it is not standard SPARQL 1.1).

```
LET(?_Email2 := str(?_Email))
```

otherwise contact the androjena project.